# ASP.NET web application I Can’t Access after IIS hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5, excel-interop

I have to read an exist excel sheet values and generate text format report using

> Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel namespace

when I deploy an ASP.NET web application on IIS 7.5 at windows server 8 r2 I can't access that event after IIS hosting but when I run local machine it'll working fine... kindly give me the solution on this problem? Following my aspx.cs code.

```
using System.Data;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

public void GetTextValue()
{
    string sUploadFilePath = string.Empty;

    sUploadFilePath = Server.MapPath(".") + @"\Report\GAD_Model_Template_keivsan1_D2038_00.xls";

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    //Office Application Object Declaretion

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL = null;

    //Office workbook object  Declaretion

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook oWB = null;

    //Office Worksheet object  Declaretion

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet oSheet = null;

    //Office Range object  Declaretion

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range oRng = null;

    try
    {

        //Create an Application object                   

        oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        //Getting a WorkBook object

        oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(sUploadFilePath, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);

        //Getting a WorkSheet object                   

        oSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)oWB.Sheets["OUTPUT"];

        //Datatable with dtExcel Name

        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable("dtExcel");

        ds.Tables.Add(dt);

        DataRow dr;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        //Total Column Count

        int jValue = oSheet.UsedRange.Cells.Columns.Count;

        //Total Row count   

        int iValue = oSheet.UsedRange.Cells.Rows.Count;

        for (int j = 1; j <= jValue; j++)
        {

            dt.Columns.Add("column" + j, System.Type.GetType("System.String"));

        }

        //Getting Data in Cell                   

        for (int i = 1; i <= iValue; i++)
        {

            dr = ds.Tables["dtExcel"].NewRow();

            for (int j = 1; j <= jValue; j++)
            {

                oRng = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)oSheet.Cells[i, j];

                string strValue = oRng.Text.ToString();

                dr["column" + j] = strValue;

            }

            ds.Tables["dtExcel"].Rows.Add(dr);

        }

        //Release the Excel objects                

        oWB.Close(false, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value);

        oXL.Workbooks.Close();

        oXL.Quit();

        oXL = null;

        oWB = null;

        oSheet = null;

        oRng = null;

        GC.GetTotalMemory(false);

        GC.Collect();

        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        GC.Collect();

        GC.GetTotalMemory(true);

        //Release the Excel objects          

        StringBuilder commaDelimitedText = new StringBuilder();
        commaDelimitedText.AppendLine("GAD Inputs");
        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["dtExcel"].Rows)
        {
            string value = string.Format("{0}", row[0]); // how you format is up to you (spaces, tabs, delimiter, etc)
            commaDelimitedText.AppendLine(value);
        }

        File.WriteAllText("" + Server.MapPath(".") + @"\Report\" + "GADoutput" + ".txt" + "", commaDelimitedText.ToString());
        string txtfilepath = Server.MapPath(".") + @"\Report\" + "GADoutput" + ".txt";
        Session["filepath"] = txtfilepath;

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "SITE", "alert('Text File Write successfully!');", true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)

    { }

    //return ds;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: you have to register the excel interop in your IIS using com componant

Comment: Server side Office automation like you did, is not supported, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757